# PHP5.3 is not working with MySQL5.1 IIS7 Times out

Tags: php, mysql, iis, ipv6

I have set up PHP5.3, MySQL5.1, and IIS7 on Window 7 but php doesn't want to work with MySQL. I'm assuming it is a configuration error or an incomplete install on my part.

1. MySQL5.1 is working
2. PHP5.3 is working, phpinfo() shows info and that i have enabled MySQL
3. IIS is setup and using fastCgiModule to run PHP
4. IIS registers php.ini updates
5. port 3306 is firewall free and open to the world
6. php.ini is configured correctly
7. I have added c:\php to the Windows systems PATH

In the past I remember moving a file, libmysql.dll, to System32 but I doesn't look like that come with php5.3.1, as the driver comes built in now https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.install.php.

(This has been giving me so much trouble I have been documenting my findings on my blog as http://inteldesigner.com/2010/code/having-problems-getting-php5-3-to-work-with-mysql5-1 )

**NEED**:

1. I need to install PHP manually, don't want to use the quick installer or an older version
2. I need to get PHP5.3 to work with MySQL5.1 so i can install Wordpress2.9 and Drupal7a

Any links or suggestion would be great, I have already done everything on the iis web site, nothing is working. I'm guessing they have not updated for new software.

**BUGS/SOLUTION**:

*The solution is here*: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50172 thanks go to don.raman on the iis.net forums http://forums.iis.net/p/1164911/1933894.aspx

**SYMPTOMS**:

The php function `mysql_connect()` in conjunction with php5.3 locks up sever and returns error 500. (IPv6 is the problem see above link)

**TEST CODE**:

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","***");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    
    // some code
    
    mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

**ERRORS**:

From Browser:

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
C:\php\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exceeded configured activity timeout
```

When i run `php -f c:\public_html\index.php` from the command line i got:

```
PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): [2002] A connection attempt failed because the co
nnected party did not  (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:3306) in C:\public
_html\index.php on line 10

Warning: mysql_connect(): [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connect
ed party did not  (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:3306) in C:\public_html
\index.php on line 10
PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): A connection attempt failed because the connected
 party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connectio
n failed because connected host has failed to respond.
 in C:\public_html\index.php on line 10

Warning: mysql_connect(): A connection attempt failed because the connected part
y did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection fai
led because connected host has failed to respond.
 in C:\public_html\index.php on line 10
Could not connect: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did n
ot properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed bec
ause connected host has failed to respond.

C:\Users\Kevin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don.raman wrote:

> Please look at http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50172 for resolution on this.
>
> Another alternative is to to use PHP 5.2.12 which doesn't have this behavior.

I found it http://forums.iis.net/p/1164911/1933894.aspx and posted about it.

Comment: That worked.  Here's the short circuit link http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50172   So in my case changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 got the connection going.

Answer (score 0):

I had the my_sql_connect error with Windows 7/Apache/MySql.
Changing host parameter from 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' also worked for me.

Also for other hosts just use the IP address instead of the host name (type 'ping ' from a command prompt if you want to find its IP address quickly).

Answer (score -1):

Do this:

- Go to `C://Windows/System32/drivers/etc`
- Edit the file called `host`

Before you do anything make sure you have enough permissions to edit it, right click on it Go to PROPERTIES->SECURITY->EDIT then choose the user account you are using and give full control to it by clicking on Full Control check box, then Apply->Ok

Open `host` file using notepad or any other ANSI standard text editor and uncomment the line `# 127.0.0.1 localhost` by removing `#` and save.